# Python list of dict into a 2D list

Tags: python

**Input**

Couldn't get my head round this: I've got a python list of dictionaries like so:

```py
d = [{'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'b': ['b1', 'b2']}, {...}, {...}]
```

Important notes:

- number of keys ('a', 'b' ...) is const (e.g. from A to Z)
- lengths of values (lists) is arbitrary, it may even be an empty list
- elements in values don't matter and are here shown as 'a1', 'b2' for clarity only

**Expected result**

I need to flatten the nested lists into a 2D list of separate dicts like so:

```py
d = [ 
        [ {'key': 'a', 'val': 'a1'}, {'key': 'b', 'val': 'b1'}, {...} ],
        [ {'key': 'a', 'val': 'a2'}, {'key': 'b', 'val': 'b2'}, {...} ],
        [ {'key': 'a', 'val': 'a3'}, {'key': 'b', 'val': 'b3'}, {...} ],
        [ ... ]
    ]
```

That is, each dict is atomic containing to items: 'key' that stands for the original keys, and 'val' - the original lists broken element wise. Since the number of keys is const, the inner lists must have equal lengths. So this is basically a permutation problem.

**Note**
Since the number is elements in the values (lists) is not const, the permutations must be able to pad the shorter lists with None or use the end elements. For example:

```py
[
  [ {'key': 'a', 'val': 'a5'}, # -- last possible value for 'a' =5
    {'key': 'b', 'val': 'b100'}, # -- but 'b' has at least 100 values...
    ...
  ],
  [ {'key': 'a', 'val': 'a5'}, # -- ...so the next list uses the same val for 'a'
    {'key': 'b', 'val': 'b101'}, # -- ...and a next one for 'b'
    ...
  ],
]
```

Tried [pandas.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and various native python tricks, but just couldn't succeed... For example, `pandas.to_dict('list')` gives

```
{ 'keys': ['a', 'b', ...], 'vals': [[a1, a2, ...], ['b1', 'b2', ...]]}
```

Comment: I would avoid writing everything in a single for loop. Try to dump everything in a single dictionary where the value is the list containing everything. Then create an empty nested list with the max length obtained. Finally write the loop to append everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it finally. Here's the solution -- use Cartesian product with `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools, json

def flatten(d, sortkeys=True):
    keys = sorted(d.keys()) if sortkeys else d.keys()
    return [
        {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, list_prod_value)}
        for list_prod_value in itertools.product(*(d[k] for k in keys if d[k]))
    ]

d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 3: [7]}

print(json.dumps(flatten(d), indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "1": 1,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 1,
    "2": 6,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 2,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 2,
    "2": 6,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 3,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 3,
    "2": 6,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 4,
    "2": 5,
    "3": 7
  },
  {
    "1": 4,
    "2": 6,
    "3": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: The form of neither the input nor the output look at all like what you described in your question.